# Python . How to sort elements of sub-list if second elements are equal sort the sub-lists by first element

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list like this:

```
 list_grade = [['m' , 7.5],['h',6.75],['z',15],['a',19.63],['b',6.75]]
```

i want the exact output of this list without changing the position of sub-lists but if the second element of sub-lists are equal, sort that tow sub-lists by the first element of those two sub-lists.

my expected output:

```
 list_grade = [['m' , 7.5],['b',6.75],['z',15],['a',19.63],['h',6.75]]
```

for example the ['b',6.75] and ['h',6.75] are sorted by ***replacing*** their indexes.

Comment: The code in your question doesn’t appear related to the problem of sorting - please remove that code and and some minimal code that shows your honest attempt to solve this sorting problem, as a [mre] - with imports and some minimal data _in the code_

Comment: what will you do if there are more than 2 lists with the same element?

Comment: sort them in anyway! i mean if in sub-lists we got the equal value in output they would be shown sorted by their first element or alphabetical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_grade = [['m' , 7.5],['h',6.75],['z',15],['a',19.63],['b',6.75]]

# collect the elements by value, like
# {7.5: [['m', 7.5]], 6.75: [['h', 6.75], ['b', 6.75]], ...}
element_map = defaultdict(list)

for elem in list_grade:
    element_map[elem[1]].append(elem)
    
# sort the elements
for k in element_map:
    element_map[k].sort()

# rebuild the list
list_grade_sorted = [element_map[v].pop(0) for _,v in list_grade]
```

Comment: you are my savior @fsimonjetz